# How can I move a Windows program to the Dash?

Tags: wine, gnome-shell, 18.10, ubuntu-dock, favorites

I have a Windows program that runs under Wine. Its icon is on the Desktop but I want to move it to the Dash (favorites).

It is not found when I search in Activities so I don't get the option to move it.

It worked in 18.04 but I am using it on 18.10.

Answer (score 0):

The launcher for your program in fact is a `.desktop` file, currently living in your Desktop folder. Move (or copy, if you also want to leave it on the desktop) that file to the hidden folder `.local/share/applications`. It will then automatically be included into the Applications. From the Applications overview, you will be able to pin it into the dash (run the application, then right-click on the icon in the launcher and select "Add to favorites").

`.local` is a hidden folder in your home folder. Turn on "Show hidden files" in the file manager (tip: you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to quickly toggle the setting).